# When you upload your application on Google Play Store, what all updates can you do in the next version of the same app?

Tags: android, google-play, updates

Suppose I uploaded my application on Google Play and everybody downloads it. Later I want to update it.
Will i be able to do the following things?

1) Suppose there is a class say ExampleClass, Re-write that class and save it.
2) Make changes to various functions?
3) Edit pre existing XML layout files?

Basically i want to know what can be done in an update. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Will i be able to do the following things?

Yes.

> Basically i want to know what can be done in an update.

Pretty much whatever you want. The entire APK is replaced on an update.

If you are saving data in files, databases, `SharedPreferences`, or the Internet, *that* is where you will need to keep tabs on what you are updating, to offer compatibility for all versions of your app. User data on the device is retained on an update, and so you can have a newer app referring to older data.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically i want to know what can be done in an update.

Whatever you want. Google Play does not care as long as your `applicationId` and signing certificate matches application new one is expected to be update of, it is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you can even upload an other diferent app, just the signature have to be the same.

The only case you have to consider is the database if you app use one, if you change the estruture of it, you first have to save the user data an then put that data in the new estructure.